# Mandar o resultado de duas tabelas MySQL para uma view (ejs)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-js, ejs

Estou trabalhando com Ejs e Node.JS com MySQL. Preciso passar para uma view calculo info de duas tabelas, porem me deparo com esse erro:

```
app.get("/calc", (req, res)=>{
    Palpite.findAll().then(calc =>{
        res.render("calc/index", {calc: calc})
    }).then(()=>{
        RPalpite.findAll().then(rp =>{
            res.render("calc/index", {rp: rp})
        })
    })
})
```

Erro:

> ReferenceError: rp is not defined

```html
<% rp.forEach(rpal=>{ %>
  <tr>
      <th scope="row"><%= rpal.id %></th>
      <th scope="row"><%= rpal.rp1 %></th>
      <th scope="row"><%= rpal.rp2 %></th>
      <th scope="row"><%= rpal.rp3 %></th>
      <th scope="row"><%= rpal.rp4 %></th>
      <th scope="row"><%= rpal.rp5 %></th>
  </tr>
<% }) %>
```

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao SO! Para que as pessoas possam te ajudar melhor, tente descrever melhor o que você fez e o resultado que gostaria de ter com o código. Perguntas mais detalhadas ajudam no entendimento da dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você deseja adicionar adicionar as duas informações no template.

Segue um exemplo de como pode ser feito:

```
app.get("/calc", (req, res)=>{
    Palpite.findAll().then(calc =>{
        req.calc = calc
    }).then(()=>{
        RPalpite.findAll().then(rp =>{
            res.render("calc/index", {rp: rp, rpal: req.calc })
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Deu certo muito obrigado, excelente!!!